# Wi-FI Direct tutorial - Where does the PeerListListener go?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi-direct, peer

Using this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#fetch

I have gotten to this section of code in the tutorial successfully:

```
 private List peers = new ArrayList();
...

private PeerListListener peerListListener = new PeerListListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {

        // Out with the old, in with the new.
        peers.clear();
        peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

        // If an AdapterView is backed by this data, notify it
        // of the change.  For instance, if you have a ListView of available
        // peers, trigger an update.
        ((WiFiPeerListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (peers.size() == 0) {
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "No devices found");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I am now unsure of where to put this code that obtains a peer list. Does it go in my broadcast receiver, or the wifi activity itself? And where?

Comment: No. I'm still not seeing it. I do not understand where it should be in onRecieve(). Sorry for being new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you continue with the example, you can see that the object created in the code you posted (`peerListListener`) is used in the `onReceive()` method. Seems like they screwed up and renamed it to `peerListener` there though.

Comment: So it should be in onRecieve? Or before it?

Comment: At the class level, whichever class owns `onReceive()` (the broadcast receiver).